# How to subtract the two columns sum of amount using linq

Tags: linq

Below my query which not working properly could any one help here?

```
enter code here 
       var collectionamount = (from u in db.bank_deposit
                                    join pr in db.collections on u.AgentID equals pr.AgentID into g
                                    join agentname in db.agent_master on u.AgentID equals agentname.AgentID
                                    group u by new { u.AgentID } into x
                                    select new collectionwithdeposit
                                    {
                                        AgentName = agentname.AgentName,
                                        DepositedAmount = g.Sum(m => m.DepositedAmount),
                                        CollectionAmount = g.Sum(z => z.AmountReceived),
                                        Balance = g.Sum(u => u.DepositedAmount) - g.Sum(v => v.AmountReceived)
                                    }).ToList();

            lstdataModel.Add(dataModel);

        }
```

Comment: what issue are you facing?

Comment: some compile errors which I had written query is not is good syntax

Comment: Error 5 The name 'g' does not exist in the current context 
Error 6   The name 'agentname' does not exist in the current context

Comment: unable to the sum of colelctio amount CollectionAmount = g.Sum(z => z.AmountReceived),

Comment: if you can provide the classes then it will be more helpful

Comment: classes this is action in mvc controller and check my edited question that properties class

Comment: `agentname` is not being recognized because of your group by query

Comment: please check my question I edited my query like that it's fine but unable to get the name of agentname form table3record how to do that?

Comment: yes cause you have not inclued it in your group :)

Comment: {"Unable to create a constant value of type 'jquerynestedgrid.Models.agent_master'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."}

Comment: when I run my query this  is the error ocuured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `g` does not exists in the scope of your `select`. This is because of the `into` keyword. What you are writing is in effect..

```
var tempEnumerable = from u in db.bank_deposit
                     join pr in db.collections on u.AgentID equals pr.AgentID into g
                     join agentname in db.agent_master on u.AgentID equals agentname.AgentID
                     group u by new { u.AgentID };
var collectionamount = from x in tempEnumerable
                                    select new collectionwithdeposit
                                    {
                                        AgentName = agentname.AgentName,
                                        DepositedAmount = g.Sum(m => m.DepositedAmount),
                                        CollectionAmount = g.Sum(z => z.AmountReceived),
                                        Balance = g.Sum(u => u.DepositedAmount) - g.Sum(v => v.AmountReceived)
                                    }).ToList();
```

The `into` keyword in Linq is for creating a new scope.

In fact you really don't want to use into as often as you do

Try this

```
var collectionAmount = from u in db.bank_deposit
                     where db.collections.Any(pr => pr.AgentID == u.AgentID)
                     join agentname in db.agent_master on u.AgentID equals agentname.AgentID
                     group u by agentname into g
                     select new collectionwithdeposit
                     {
                         AgentName = g.Key.AgentName,
                         DepositedAmount = g.Sum(m => m.DepositedAmount),
                         CollectionAmount = g.Sum(z => z.AmountReceived),
                         Balance = g.Sum(u => u.DepositedAmount) - g.Sum(v => v.AmountReceived)
                     }
```

EDITED:

Maybe actually what you want is this...I don't know your table structures. But I am going to assume you have no idea about Linq, and your tables are sane (since my last answer assumed the opposite).

```
var collectionAmount = from agent in db.agent_master
                       let depositedAmount = db.bank_deposit
                               .Where(d => d.AgentID == agent.AgentID)
                               .Sum(d => c.DepositedAmount)
                       let collectionAmount = db.collections
                               .Where(c => c.AgentID == agent.AgentID)
                               .Sum(c => c.AmountReceived)
                       select new collectionwithdeposit
                       {
                         AgentName = agent.AgentName,
                         DepositedAmount = depositedAmount,
                         CollectionAmount = collectionAmount,
                         Balance = depositedAmount - collectionAmount
                       }
```

Comment: 'AmountReceived' is not found

Comment: I don't know your table schema/class structure. This means that the class `BankDeposit` does not have a property `AmountReceived`.

Comment: looks like your schema does not include primary keys for the Collection and Deposit tables. That is bad.

Comment: yes that's the reason I am using linq joins why because both the tables should have the duplication data

Comment: The cast to value type 'Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type. error when checking the result in resultview

Comment: hi aron please check my edited question which I had treid in different way(new query ) it's giving exception "{"Unable to create a constant value of type 'jquerynestedgrid.Models.agent_master'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context"

Comment: and both columns are in decimal